# how to make Active Buttons once it is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have this code where I link few flies in an IFrame, i want the color of the selected button to change and remain different until another button is pressed.

```
<style>

.myButton:active 
{
position:relative; 
top:1px;


}  
</style>


<a class="myButton " href="" target="someFrame">Button1</a>
<a class="myButton " href="" target="someFrame" >Button 02</a> 
<a class="myButton " href="" target="someFrame">Button 03</a> 
<a class="myButton " href="" target="someFrame">Button 04</a> 
<a class="myButton " " target="someFrame" >Button 05</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is have a JS/jQuery function that is called when the button is pressed. That function would be something like the pseudo code below:

```
function(){
    removeClassFromOtherButtons('activeClass');
    this.addClass('activeClass');
}
```

Then in your CSS, have `.activeClass` have a different colored background.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer a solution without JavaScript, you can achieve that with some hidden radiobutton trickery:

```css
input[type="radio"][name="toggleRadio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"][name="toggleRadio"] + a label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"][name="toggleRadio"]:checked + a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="toggleRadio" id="toggleRadio1"><a href="" target="someFrame"><label class="myButton" for="toggleRadio1">Button1</label></a>
<input type="radio" name="toggleRadio" id="toggleRadio2"><a href="" target="someFrame"><label class="myButton" for="toggleRadio2">Button2</label></a>
<input type="radio" name="toggleRadio" id="toggleRadio3"><a href="" target="someFrame"><label class="myButton" for="toggleRadio3">Button3</label></a>
<input type="radio" name="toggleRadio" id="toggleRadio4"><a href="" target="someFrame"><label class="myButton" for="toggleRadio4">Button4</label></a>
<input type="radio" name="toggleRadio" id="toggleRadio5" checked><a href="" target="someFrame"><label class="myButton" for="toggleRadio5">Button5</label></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your css file create an `.active` class that will be added to a button when pressed and removed from the others.

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.myButton');
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        toggleClass(buttons, this);
  });
});

function toggleClass(buttons, buttonToActivate) {
  buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
      btn.classList.remove('active');
  });
  buttonToActivate.classList.add('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the `:active` is a :pseudo-class that is used when the button or anchor is being pressed.

If you want to your button to have a active state you need mark it with another class.

```js
var buttons =  document.querySelectorAll('.myButton');
var activeClassName = 'active';

function activeState(items, activeName) {
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if(items[i].classList.contains(activeName)) {
      items[i].classList.remove(activeName);
    }
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    activeState(buttons, activeClassName);
    e.target.classList.add(activeClassName);
  });
}
```

```css
.myButton {
  position:relative; 
  top:1px;
}

.myButton.active {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton">Test 1</button>
<button class="myButton">Test 2</button>
<button class="myButton">Test 3</button>
<button class="myButton">Test 4</button>
<button class="myButton">Test 5</button>
<button class="myButton">Test 6</button>
```

I used here vanilla javascript but this code can be re-written using ES6 or Jquery and it will be much more simple.

Here some reference links for you:

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList
- https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Once you click the button call onclick function
Use common class name to remove active class from all buttons then add active class to specific button

In css give color which you want selected button to be

```
.active{
background:red;}
```

Onclick function

```
$(".mybutton").on("click",function(event){ addclassactive(event.target);
}

function addclassactive (caller){
$(".mybutton").removeClass("active");
$(caller).addClass("active"):
}
```